# Mounting two nested read-only mount points in docker

Tags: docker, mount, readonly

I have a `docker-compose` file runs PHP and mounts some volumes in a nested way. It's been working for two years. Recently I've tried it again, and it fails, at least on Docker for WSL 2. Here are the mounted volumes from the docker-compose file.

```
volumes:
   - ../src:/var/www/html:ro
   - ./userData:/var/www/html/userData:ro
```

Note that the second volume is mounted inside the first volume.

Docker fails to mount the second directory, claiming it can't update a read only file system. I can remove the `:ro` from the first mount and it works, however - I really do want both mounts to be read-only, and I would like to keep the external file system (with `src` and `userData`) as it is.

How can I get this mounting behavior working again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it. The nested mound needs to create directory on your file system.

So your solutions are:

- Disable readonly for  `- ../src:/var/www/html:ro`
- Create link `ln -s ./userData ../src/userData`
- Do not use nested mounts, it's a bad practice. So your conteiner requires redesign.

References: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26051

Comment: Are you able to quantify why nested mounts are bad practice or provide any references to that effect? Nested bind mounts are normal and absolutely fine in Linux. I'm having a hard time figuring out why docker would be any different.